# Sort one dimensional array into two dimensional

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

```
private double[] myNumbers = {10, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4};
private double[][] result;

private double[][] divideNumbers(double[] derp) {

    int j = 0, k = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < derp.length; i++) {
        if (derp[i] >=4 && derp[i] <=8) {
            result[1][j] = derp[i];
            j++;
        }
        else {
            result[0][k] = derp[i];
            k++;
        }
    }


    //System.out.println(result[0] +"  "+ result[1]);
    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to sort the one dimensional array in to a matrix, where numbers between 4 - 8 are in one, and all other numbers are in the other.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be working. result should be result = divideNumber(myNumbers)

Comment: where is the instantiation of "result" array?

Comment: Where have you initialized your array of array?

Comment: Please note that Java does not have multidimensional arrays; there are only jagged arrays. So you can get _out of bound exception_ with `result[1][j]` and `result[0][k]`

Comment: @user1706295, you need to post more details, 1) what are you trying to achieve? 2) what output you were expecting and what you are getting? 3) is exception occuring (if yes, please post stacktrace)

Answer (score 0):

1) You're not initializing result[][]. You will get a NullPointerException.

Either loop through `myNumbers`, count the number of values for each category, and create `result[][]`, or push your values into an `ArrayList<Double>[2]` and use `List.toArray()` to convert back to an array.

2) result[][] is declared outside your method. While technically valid, it's generally poor form if there is not a specific reason for doing so. Since you're already returning double[][] you might want to declare a double[][] inside your function to work with and return.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following exactly what you want, but this should allow your code to work.

```
class OneDimToTwoDim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declare myNumbers one dimensional array
        double[] myNumbers = {10, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4};

        // display two dimensional array
        for (int x = 0; x < myNumbers.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("[" + myNumbers[x] + "] "); // Display the string.
        }

        // pass in myNumbers argument for derp parameter, and return a two dimensional array called resultNumbers
        double[][] resultNumbers = OneDimToTwoDim.divideNumbers(myNumbers);

        System.out.println(); // Display the string.
        System.out.println(); // Display the string.

        for (int x = 0; x < resultNumbers.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < resultNumbers[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.print("[" + resultNumbers[x][y] + "] "); // Display the string.
            }
            System.out.println(); // Display the string.
        }
    }

    private static double[][] divideNumbers(double[] derp) {

        // declare result to be returned 
        double[][] result = new double[2][derp.length];

        int j = 0, k = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < derp.length; i++) {
            if (derp[i] >=4 && derp[i] <=8) {
                    result[1][j] = derp[i];
                    j++;
            }
            else {
                    result[0][k] = derp[i];
                    k++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your result array isn't initialized. Are you getting null pointer exceptions? Is that the problem?

```
private static double[] myNumbers = {10, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4};
private static double[][] result = new double[2][myNumbers.length];
private static double[][] divideNumbers(double[] derp) {
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < derp.length; i++) {
        if (derp[i] >=4 && derp[i] <=8) {
            result[1][j] = derp[i];
            j++;
        }
        else {
            result[0][k] = derp[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(result[0],0,k);
    result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(result[1],0,j);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you are not sure of what the question is, you should first clarify it first in comments.

Comment: Given his question, this is the only possible logical answer.

Comment: What is it with your last two lines before `return`?

Comment: It'll get rid of default 0.0's that are created during the initialization of the results array.

Comment: Ideally you'd use an array list and use the .toArray() method if you want to be even more space efficient.